# UnityEvent not showing dynamic method call in inspector (other unity events broke partially too)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

I have this unity event

```
[Serializable]
public class UnityEventString : UnityEvent<string>
{
}
```

Which gets used in this `MonoBehaviour`

```
public class EventListenerString : MonoBehaviour, IEventListener<string>
{
    //some more code
    public EventString Event;
    public UnityEventString Response;
    //Some more code
}
```

Problem is, it doesn't show this method in inspector as dynamic.

```
    public void Show(string key)
    {
        _Show(Animator.StringToHash(key));
    }

    public void Hide(string key)
    {
        _Hide(Animator.StringToHash(key));
    }
```

[image]

I used to use this pattern for my other events too, and they worked fine until today.
Currently, there are the right methods in the inspector, from earlier this week when i programmed. But today everything stopped working for that.
[image: Unity events stopped working Picture]

It also stopped working on a plain test object with a test `MonoBehaviour` with just one method.

But it still works with that one here
[image: Working picture]

What happened here?

Comment: It is a known Issue: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/events-generated-by-the-player-input-component-do-not-have-callbackcontext-set-as-their-parameter-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attaching a function to run when the event is fired, that function is on a class, the class is a script attached to a gameobject, unity serializes this hooked method as follows GameObject Instance ID -> Script ID -> Method Name -> Parameters.
Now if you move your script to another game object, the serialization system doesn't find said script on the old game object anymore. so the deserialization breaks on the second step, and so does your hooked method.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think unity 2019.2.5 is bugged, going down to 2019.2.4 fixed this for me, all dynamic events came back.