# UnityEvent with dynamic parameters not showing anymore in the Unity inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have had a problem for a few days that didn't exist before: UnityEvent no longer manages parameters.

At first I thought it was related to the Unity version because I updated to 2019.3b, even returning in 2019.2.5f1 the problem exists.

[Unity inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADSs0.png)

As you can see in the image, the "dynamic" elements are no longer displayed and the type is not present next to the event name.

The code is extremely simple:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

[Serializable] public class VoidEvent : UnityEvent { }
[Serializable] public class BoolEvent : UnityEvent<bool> { }
[Serializable] public class IntEvent : UnityEvent<int> { }
[Serializable] public class StringEvent : UnityEvent<string> { }

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] VoidEvent voidEvent = null;
    [SerializeField] BoolEvent boolEvent = null;
    [SerializeField] IntEvent intEvent = null;
    [SerializeField] StringEvent stringEvent = null;

    public void OnVoidEvent()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnVoidEvent");
    }

    public void OnBoolEvent(bool value)
    {
        Debug.Log($"OnBoolEvent {value}");
    }

    public void OnIntEvent(int value)
    {
        Debug.Log($"OnIntEvent {value}");
    }

    public void OnStringEvent(string value)
    {
        Debug.Log($"OnStringEvent {value}");
    }
}
```

I've tried the same code on another computer, the same problem exists. I'm on OSX using Visual studio code and Unity 2019.3b and 2019.2.5f1.

Comment: But OnStringEvent shows (string) after it.. it looks normal to me

Comment: Normally there is a "dynamic" part at the top of the list that allows you to bind the method with a dynamic argument. With the bug I can just indicate the value of the string from the editor. An example [with dynamic binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ach5y.png)

Comment: Can you try with an empty project? I suspect that when you upgraded your project to the beta it broke it.... Also you can try to delete the Library and Temp folder in the root of your project

Comment: Just confirmed it! .. and related https://stackoverflow.com/q/57897807/7111561 -  though the answer there is nonsense (at least as answer to the question ^^ ) ..

Comment: @LudovicFeltz I tried with a new project too, same problem

Comment: You are right it's an issue in Unity. See my answer, just found the issue in their Issue Tracker...

Comment: It is a known Issue: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/events-generated-by-the-player-input-component-do-not-have-callbackcontext-set-as-their-parameter-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found your issue in the [Unity Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/). It's a known issue that is resolved in version 2019.3.

You can see the issue here:

- [UNITY EVENTS THAT HAVE ARGUMENTS CANNOT BE USED ANYMORE](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/unity-events-that-have-arguments-cannot-be-used-anymore)

which is a duplicate of:

- [UNITYEVENT DRAWER NO LONGER HANDLES EVENTS IN NON-PUBLIC FIELDS CORRECTLY](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/events-generated-by-the-player-input-component-do-not-have-callbackcontext-set-as-their-parameter-type)

Edit: this bug is found in versions: 2019.2.1f1, 2019.3.0a12, 2019.3.0b1, 2020.1.0a2

Comment: Thank you, Unity just told me the same thing by email, sorry for the noise! (I don't know for the down vote, it's someone else)